# JTable Data Duplicate, after populating

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In my case once I open the window for the first time data shows without any issue.

[image: Case 1]

But the issue arise when I close the window and re-open it. When it does, It shows me Duplicate data as I shown in the pictures.

[image: Case 2]

I used to close the record set, statement and connection close. But nothing happened. I use JDBC:ODBC Method to connect to the database and Vector method to populate data to jTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot clear table model before populate

```
class MyTableModel implements AbstractTableModel {
    private List<MyDomain> data = ...
    ...

    public void clear() {
        data.clear();               // clear container
        fireTableDataChanged();     // notify listeners 
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Please tell me how to do that with a sample code, I'm very beginning to JAVA.

Comment: Thanks Dude. I'll Do that.

Comment: FYI, if you're using a `DefaultTableModel`, you can set the row count to `0`